# <asp:TextBox> must hide time, only show date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `<asp:TextBox>` that I made as hidden with a date value from a SQL table.

> Expected: 05/23/2017
>
> Result: 05/23/2017 12:00:00 AM

Below are my codes for the `TextBox` and the binding:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOrdered" runat="server" class="form-control" ReadOnly="true" />
```

---

```
void GetOrderHead(int ID)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ID);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ltID.Text = dr["OrderNo"].ToString();
                txtOrderNo.Text = dr["OrderNo"].ToString();
                txtDateOrdered.Text = dr["DateOrdered"].ToString();
                txtPreparedBy.Text = dr["PreparedBy"].ToString();
                txtStatus.Text = dr["Status"].ToString();
                txtBalance.Text = dr["Balance"].ToString();
                txtTotal.Text = dr["TotalAmount"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

---

Note: I found a answer for this by using `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");` & `.ToShortDateString();` and both didn't work.

Comment: try this-
txtDateOrdered.Text =  dr.Field<DateTime>("DateOrdered").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

Comment: Simply try following Code if you just want to save it in textbox and utilise it else where  :
 txtDateOrdered.Text = dr["DateOrdered"].ToString().Split(' ')[0]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
void GetOrderHead(int ID)
    {
        string[] formats= { "MM/dd/yyyy" }

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ID);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                ltID.Text = dr["OrderNo"].ToString();
                txtOrderNo.Text = dr["OrderNo"].ToString();
                txtDateOrdered.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["DateOrdered"].ToString(), formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None); //changing format.
                txtPreparedBy.Text = dr["PreparedBy"].ToString();
                txtStatus.Text = dr["Status"].ToString();
                txtBalance.Text = dr["Balance"].ToString();
                txtTotal.Text = dr["TotalAmount"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also change Date Format in Sql Query.

```
SELECT OrderNo, CONVERT(VARCHAR(101), DateOrdered) as DateOrdered, PreparedBy, Status, Balance, TotalAmount FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = @OrderNo
```

or Parse Datetime using `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dr["DateOrdered"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```